# "The directive is missing a 'src' attribute" when registering a Custom Control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-controls

I'm trying to register a "Custom Control" (sometimes called "Custom Server Control", but not a "User Control") on an aspx page from an assembly, but at runtime I get the error: `The directive is missing a 'src' attribute`.

My Register directive on the page is:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="CMS.Controls" Namespace="CMS.Controls.Content" TagPrefix="cc" %>
```

As far as I know, the `src` attribute of the `Register` directive is only used when registering a "User Control" (i.e. a control defined by an ascx-file).

Why could I be getting this error when I'm registering a Custom Control via assembly? I made sure the assembly ("CMS.Controls.dll") is in the bin directory of my project.

Comment: Did you follow the doc steps ? https://support.microsoft.com/es-ec/help/321749/how-to-register-an-assembly-in-a-webform-to-use-a-custom-control

Comment: Pretty much, except that the referenced assembly is a referenced project, so the resulting dll file is generated in my project's bin directory automatically.

Comment: Have you tried to clean/rebuild your solution in both debug and release ?

Comment: I hadn't yet! Good idea. Unfortunately, there is no change.

Comment: Try to register the top namespace => Namespace="CMS.Controls"

Comment: Do you have other Register directives on your page ?

Comment: @B.Lec: I don't have any other Register directives on my page. Changing the namespace doesn't do the trick either.

Comment: I have no more clue. you should perhaps try to add the controls to your toolbox and drag/drop them and see if VS does the job.  http://devnet.kentico.com/docs/5_5r2/controls/index.html?configuring_your_project_for_kentico_cms_controls.htm

Comment: I've added the control to the toolbox, but when I drag the control on a page, it simply generates the same Register directive as I already had. The error persists as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, this is embarrassing, but pay attention to the file name mentioned in the error! Apparently, I had been adding the Register directive to multiple files in my quest to get it working, and the error was pointing at the one I put there earlier but forgot about… The directive in the OP is correct.

Also make sure you have the correct namespace! You can also get this error if you put an incorrect namespace.